# Make Editable MathJax?

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

I want to know if there is anyway to make an editable MathJax element. Similar to `contenteditable` in a div.

I have this **HTML**:

```html
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>

<head>
    <title>Reducir matriz</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <math>
            <mrow data-mjx-texclass="INNER">
              <mo data-mjx-texclass="OPEN">(</mo>
              <mtable columnspacing="1em" rowspacing="4pt">
                <mtr>
                  <mtd>
                    <mi>a</mi>
                  </mtd>
                  <mtd>
                    <mi>b</mi>
                  </mtd>
                </mtr>
                <mtr>
                  <mtd>
                    <mi>c</mi>
                  </mtd>
                  <mtd>
                    <mi>d</mi>
                  </mtd>
                </mtr>
              </mtable>
              <mo data-mjx-texclass="CLOSE">)</mo>
            </mrow>
          </math>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want to be able to change the *a, b, c, d* values. Any ideas? Should I use js to achieve this?

Comment: In-place editing does not seem possible - there are examples how to render user entered input though: https://mathjax.github.io/MathJax-demos-web/input-tex_mml2chtml.html

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answer, I will take a look

Comment: HTML5 note: math elements do not use XML namespacing. It's just `<math>` (and just `<svg>`) without the xmlns attribute. The `<math>` element is [an official HTML5 element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/MathML/Element/math), not an out-of-spec tag. Also, if you're putting `<math>` in its own block (through a `<div>` element) you don't need `display="block"`, the div's already doing that for you.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, the `display="block"` is still necessary for the Math to be interpreted as a displayed equation.  There are different layout rules for inline versus displayed equations, and this attribute tells the render which set to use.  That can't be inherited from the `div` because the `math` tag could be part of a line of text within the `div`, and so be in-line math.  Note that the attribute `display="block"` is not the same as `style="display: block"`.

Comment: ah, good to know.